# How to make webbrowserextensions::printtopdfasync to evaluate the printed page with screen media type?

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Here is a example HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>

        <title>Test iframe</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            #node1 {
                color: red;
            }
            @media only screen {
                #node2 {
                    color: blue;
                }
            }
            @media only print {
                #node2 {
                    color: yellow;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="node1">Hello</div>
        <div id="node2">World</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

When using cefsharp to open the page and use webbrowserextensions::printtopdfasync to print it to PDF, I want the color of #node2 is blue. But actually, the color is black.

Is there any way to make the css for screen media type to function in the printed PDF?

Comment: How does Chrome behave if you print your HTML to PDF?

Comment: It takes the print media type's style and the color is #node2 is yellow.

Comment: But, puppeteer (a headless chromium's controller) provides a API emulateMedia to make the PDF printed by puppeteer take screen media type's style. The usage is page.emulateMedia('screen')

Comment: That's likely a bug in `CEF` then. You can use `puppateer` with `CEF`. `CefSharp` is just a `.Net` wrapper around https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src

Comment: Thanks! But my project has already used CefSharp. It's not convenient to change to use puppeteer.

Comment: You can use puppeteer Sharp in addition to CefSharp.